# Problem with chown and vsftpd too slow

Tags: permissions, vsftpd, chown, filezilla

So me and a couple of friends have a ubuntu 20.04 server. We installed vsftpd to connect with filezilla and be able to upload and download files.
After like 1 hour playing with the permissions to allow us to modify the entire home directory (without success) ive decided to ask here.

We have basically two problems.

1. We want to grant permissions to every 3 of us to modify the entire home directory, we tried with this
   sudo addgroup owner
   sudo sudo chown -R :owner /home
   sudo adduser  owner (to the 3 of us)

We should be able to access the entire home directory, and all subdirectoris (and files), right? But thats not the case. I can only access my directory (/home/myuser) and my other partners home directories (/home/myfriend) but i cant access things like (/home/myuser/subdire) i get

```
Response:   550 Failed to change directory.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

from filezilla.

(Correct me if im wrong, im not an expert with ubuntu)

And another thing. When i change directory to another one it takes a while (30+ seconds) to retrieve it. That only happens to me, my other 2 friends load directory almost instantly. I have 100mb/s and the server has 600mb/s

Comment: Don't mess with the permissions of /home/ Create a dedicated mount point for things like this."When i change directory to another one it takes a while (30+ seconds) to retrieve it."  nothing to go on here... but I would assume this is an issue with settings on your end.

Comment: @Rinzwind What do you mean by "dedicated mount point" Like a specific folder inside home directory?

Comment: No /home should be the home of a user or users. So it is personal. A dedicated mount point is a directory on disc. Like a directory /ftp/  or whatever you want to name it. You then set that location to a specific GROUP and add all users to that group.